# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ExamQuestions.Employees.Number' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

Below is query-

```
select
    Employees.Number,
    Employees.Surname,
    Employees.ProjectName
from
    ExamQuestions.Projects p,
    ExamQuestions.Employees e
where
    p.Number = e.Number;
```

Comment: I have no idea why it is giving me this error, I have the correct syntax and conditions as far as my notes go, any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you have defined table aliases, you need to use them:

```
SELECT e.Number, e.Surname, p.ProjectName
FROM ExamQuestions.Projects p JOIN
     ExamQuestions.Employees e
     ON p.Number = e.Number;
```

Presumably, the project name comes from `Projects` and not `Employees`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!!